# $p$-valued pro-$p$ groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, profinite-groups

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $G$ a finitely generated pro-$p$ group. We say that $G$ is *$p$-valued* if there exits a map $\omega:G\to \mathbb{R}_{>0}\cup \{\infty\}$, which is called *valuation*, such that the following properties hold for all $g,h\in G$:

1. $ \omega(g)>\frac{1}{p-1} $,
2. $\omega(g)=\infty$ if and only if $g=1$,
3. $ \omega(g^{-1}h)\geq \min\{\omega(g),\omega(h)\} $,
4. $\omega(g^{-1}h^{-1}gh )\geq \omega(g)+\omega(h)$,
5. $ \omega(g^{p})=\omega(g)+1 $.

Lazard uses the valuation $\omega$ to define a topology on $G$ by choosing the subgroup $G_{\nu}=\{g\in G~|~ \omega(g)\geq \nu\}$, with $\nu \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, as a fundamental system of neighborhoods of the identity. Then one can show that topology of $G$ coming from the valuation coincides with the topology of $G$ as a pro-$p$ group.

My question is the following:

> Let $G$ be a $p$-valued pro-$p$ group. Can we always find a $p$-valutation $\omega'$ on $G$ such that $\omega'(g)>1$ for all $g\in G$?

Comment: $\omega(g^{-1}h^{-1}gh )\geq \omega(g)+\omega(h)$ is a bit mysterious can you give a simple relevant example?

Comment: @reuns $\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$ Consider the first congruence subgroup $\GL_{n}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ of $\GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, i.e.
$$\GL_{n}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_p):=\ker(\GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)\to \GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)).$$ For any nonzero matrix $ A=(a_{ij}) $, we put
$ w(A):=\min_{i,j}{v_p(a_{ij})}$ where $ v_{p} $ denote the usual $ p $-adic valuation
and $ w(0):=\infty $. Finally, define $\omega(A):=w(A-I_n)$ for any $A\in \GL_{n}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ . Then one can check that $ \omega $ is a $ p $-valuation on $\GL_{n}^{1}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Comment: I see it is because assuming $v(A)\ge v(B)$ and using the geometric series and removing all the $A^2$ and $AB$ terms 
$(1+A)^{-1}(1+B)^{-1}(1+A)(1+B)
$ $=(1+A)^{-1}(1+B)^{-1}(1+A+B+AB)$ $\equiv
(1+A)^{-1}+(1+A)^{-1}(1+B)^{-1}A
\equiv (1-A)+(1-A)A\equiv 1$

Comment: So what about $\ker(GL_n(\Bbb{Z}_p[p^{1/2}])\to GL_n(\Bbb{F}_p))$ do you have a $\omega'$ ?

Comment: Note that $p$-valued pro-$p$ groups are necessarily torsion-free. So is it torsion-free? At the moment, I don't know how to define a $p$-valuation on it.

Comment: For $p\ge 5$ (to satisfy the condition 5.), $v$ is the discrete valuation on $\Bbb{Z}_p[p^{1/2}]$ such that $v(p)=1$ and $\omega(1+A)=\inf_{ij} v(A_{ij})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if $p >2$. (Whereas for $p=2$, all $p$-valuations are of this kind, by definition.)

Consider the group $G:=\{ g \in GL_2(\mathbb Q_p): w(g-I_2) > \dfrac{1}{p-1} \}$, where $w: M_2(\mathbb Q_p) \rightarrow \mathbb Z$ is the additive version of the usual supremum norm, i.e.

$$w(\pmatrix{x_1&x_2\\x_3&x_4}) := \min(v_p(x_i)).$$

$G$ is a complete $p$-valued group with the $p$-valuation

$$\omega(g) := w(g-I_2)$$

according to [Lazard](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1965__26__5_0.pdf), III. 3.2.6.

But for $p>2$, both $g:=\pmatrix{1&p\\0&1}$ and $h := \pmatrix{(p+1)^{-1}&0\\0&1}$ are in $G$, and $$g^{-1}h^{-1}gh = g^p,$$ so for any other $p$-valuation $\omega'$ such that $\omega '(h) >1$, we get a contradiction between conditions 4 and 5.